# How do I avoid writing `$type` with System.Text.Json?

Tags: c#, json, system.text.json, .net-7.0

How do I avoid exposing a type discriminator when serializing a class that has opted into polymorphic deserialization?

I'm using System.Text.Json's `JsonDerivedType` attributes to do polymorphic deserialization.  So I need to specify `typeDiscriminator` on the attribute, or else deserialization won't read incoming `$type` fields on the JSON.  But when I serialize those same classes, I don't want System.Text.Json to automatically add `$type` (exposing implmentation details, etc.).

#### Example

```cs
[JsonDerivedType(typeof(Derived1), typeDiscriminator: "Derived1")]
[JsonDerivedType(typeof(Derived2), typeDiscriminator: "Derived2")]
public record BaseType(int Id);

public record Derived1(int Id, string Name) : BaseType(Id);
public record Derived2(int Id, bool IsActive) : BaseType(Id);
```

When serializing:

```cs
var values = new List<BaseType>
{
  new Derived1(123, "Foo"),
  new Derived2(456, true)
};
JsonSerializer.Serialize(values);
```

Actual output:

```json
[
  { "$type": "Derived1", "Id": 123, "Name": "Foo" },
  { "$type": "Derived2", "Id": 456, "IsActive": true }
]
```

How do I avoid `$type` being written?

Desired output:

```json
[
  { "Id": 123, "Name": "Foo" },
  { "Id": 456, "IsActive": true }
]
```

Again, I know I could exclude `typeDiscriminator` from the attribute, but then deserialization would not work.

#### Links

- [Deserializing type hierarchies added in .NET 7](https://github.com/dotnet/runtime/issues/63747)

Comment: You have to decide what do you want - to remove type or to be able to deserialize. You can not prepare an omlet and save an egg in the same time

Comment: @Serge but I do not have to choose in Newtonsoft's JSON.NET.  I can use separate `JsonSerializerSettings` with different `TypeNameHandling` settings, which allows this exact functionality.

Comment: Actually that gives me an idea.  I can use separate settings objects for each operation instead of relying on the attributes.

Answer (score 3):

One solution is to write separate overrides of `DefaultJsonTypeInfoResolver` for serialization and deserialization, and remove the `[JsonDerivedType]` attributes.

Similar to Newtonsoft, System.Text.Json also supports polymorphic deserialization via the serializer's options as an alternative to attributes.  In Newtonsoft, you would use different values of `JsonSerializerSettings.TypeNameHandling` to affect whether `$type` is written.  System.Text.Json requires that you opt each type into this behavior explicitly, but the idea is the same.

Sample classes:

```cs
// Don't add [JsonDerivedType]
public record BaseType(int Id);

public record Derived1(int Id, string Name) : BaseType(Id);
public record Derived2(int Id, bool IsActive) : BaseType(Id);
```

Resolver for deserializing with a discriminator:

```cs
// Example taken from dotnet/runtime#63747 "Configuring Polymorphism via the Contract model"
public class DeserializeResolver : DefaultJsonTypeInfoResolver
{
    public override JsonTypeInfo GetTypeInfo(Type type, JsonSerializerOptions options)
    {
        JsonTypeInfo jsonTypeInfo = base.GetTypeInfo(type, options);
        if (jsonTypeInfo.Type == typeof(BaseType))
        {
            jsonTypeInfo.PolymorphismOptions = new JsonPolymorphismOptions()
            {
                DerivedTypes =
                {
                    // Pass in the type discriminator for this resolver.
                    new JsonDerivedType(typeof(Derived1), typeDiscriminator: "Derived1"),
                    new JsonDerivedType(typeof(Derived2), typeDiscriminator: "Derived2"),
                }
            };
        }

        return jsonTypeInfo;
    }
}
```

Resolver for serializing without a discriminator:

```cs
public class SerializeResolver : DefaultJsonTypeInfoResolver
{
    ...
    // Exact same as above resolver except:
                DerivedTypes =
                {
                    // Don't pass in the typeDiscriminator parameter.
                    new JsonDerivedType(typeof(Derived1)),
                    new JsonDerivedType(typeof(Derived2)),
                }
    ...
}
```

Then, use different instances of `JsonSerializerOptions` serialization and deserialization:

`initial`:

```json
[
  { "$type": "Derived1", "Name": "Foo", "Id": 123 },
  { "$type": "Derived2", "IsActive": true, "Id": 456 }
]
```

```cs
string initial;

var deserializeOptions = new JsonSerializerOptions
{
    TypeInfoResolver = new DeserializeResolver(),
};
var serializeOptions = new JsonSerializerOptions
{
    TypeInfoResolver = new SerializeResolver(),
};

var values = JsonSerializer.Deserialize<List<BaseType>>(initial, deserializeOptions);

// At this point, the types have been successfully deserialized via their $type.
Assert.NotNull(values);
Assert.IsAssignableFrom<Derived1>(values[0]);
Assert.IsAssignableFrom<Derived2>(values[1]);

string result = JsonSerializer.Serialize(values, serializeOptions);
```

`result`:

```json
[
  { "Name": "Foo", "Id": 123 },
  { "IsActive": true, "Id": 456 }
]
```

Answer (score 1):

I see the following options:

1. Don't use polymorphic list, e.g. have a list of `Derived1` and another list of `Derived2`
2. Change `$type` to something that you like  `[JsonPolymorphic(CustomTypeDiscriminatorPropertyName = "Kind")]`
3. Use a different name: `[JsonDerivedType(typeof(Derived1), typeDiscriminator: "A")]`, or a number `[JsonDerivedType(typeof(Derived1), typeDiscriminator: 1)]`,
4. Don't use `JsonDerivedType` and write your own deserialiser

Source: [#63747: Developers can use System.Text.Json to serialize type hierarchies securely](https://github.com/dotnet/runtime/issues/63747)